# Using URDF in static transform

Tags: urdf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible to use an URDF File for the TF Function instead of hardcoding it?

BR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64916/using-urdf-in-static-transform/) by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you want to use http://ros.org/wiki/joint_state_publisher

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eisenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3282/eisenhorn/) on 2013-06-14**:
Hey thanks for your answer. Sorry for my trivial question, but thats quite new for me. I am using the urdf with the joint_state and robot_state_publisher, but now I have the problem to correctly link the base frame to the map. Please see: http://answers.ros.org/question/65141/hector-mapping-frame-id